# scikit on Google Compute Engine: gcloud compute ssh: ssh-flag "-D" fails

Tags: ssh, scikit-learn, google-compute-engine, gcloud

My overall-goal is to run scikit-scripts on GCE and therefore I try to use Anaconda/IPython (which I use on my desktop) on GCE.

I am following this tutorial here (https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/tutorials/jupyter-notebook#verify_cluster_and_notebook_creation) but struggling on the following step:

```
gcloud compute ssh  --zone=<master-host-zone> \
  --ssh-flag="-D 1080" --ssh-flag="-N" --ssh-flag="-n" <master-host-name>
```

My console always responds with the following error message and I have no idea what is wrong:

```
unknown option "-D 1080"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've tested on my laptop with the below command (I've added -vvv flag which makes the output verbose) And it works.

gcloud compute ssh  --zone=europe-west1-b --ssh-flag=-vvv --ssh-flag="-D 1080" --ssh-flag="-N" --ssh-flag="-n" <my_host_name>

Maybe you should update your gcloud tool?

Comment: unfortunately its still not working, got the same error-message. I did a little more research and it looks like this guy here has the same issue: [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/issues/22)

Comment: Then it can be an OS dependent issue because I've also tested on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense because on Windows, `gcloud compute ssh` uses PuTTY for SSH; the PuTTY client doesn't respect the `-D` flag. You'll have to use PuTTY-specific options for creating an SSH tunnel; I'm not a Windows user so I don't know what those are.

I'll get the tutorial updated.